# CSS: Anchor height depends on font-size

Tags: css

I am trying to have a image on CSS text button. If I increase font-size to 26 px, image appear properly.I want to keep the font-size at 20px but fit image properly.

```
a.button {
  border: 1px solid #979797;
}
a.button.icon {
  padding-left: 11px;
}

a.button.icon span{
  padding-left: 48px;
  background: url(../img/gmail2.png) no-repeat;
}
a.button.icon.chat span {
  background-position: 0px -48;
}

a.button {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #dbdbdb);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,
      color-stop(0, #ffffff),color-stop(1, #dbdbdb));
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient
      (startColorStr='#ffffff', EndColorStr='#dbdbdb');
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient
      (startColorStr='#ffffff', EndColorStr='#dbdbdb')";
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: #fff 0 1px 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #597390;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about setting an specific height for a.button.icon span ?

Comment: got it, create a jsfiddle with the html and the css. Post it here and I can try to see what's going on.